# How can we prove that for every $\alpha,$ $\alpha \in aut(\mathbb Q)$ has the form $\alpha(x)=x\alpha(1)?$

Tags: group-theory

How can we prove that for every $\alpha,$$\alpha \in aut(\mathbb Q)$ has the form $\alpha(x)=x\alpha(1)?$

My try: It looks obvious but no idea of proof.

Comment: An element $\alpha\in\text{Aut}(\mathbb{Q})$ is fixed by $\alpha(1)$.

Comment: can you please elaborate ?

Comment: If $\alpha(1)=\beta$, then $\alpha(1+1)=2\beta$ and $\alpha(k)=k\beta$ for any $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. It follows that $\alpha(p/q) = (p/q)\alpha(1)$.